# Compose: Custom TopAppBar height for Material3?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

Is there a way to make a custom material3 topAppBar. What I'm looking for is to change the height, but every time I do so with TopAppBar modifier.height, the Text doesn't stay in the middle vertically, it goes up, but just text itself, the trailing icon stays in the middle as it suppose to.

```
@Composable
fun CodTopBar(
    onSearchIconClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(
                text = "CodSample",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
            )
        },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = onSearchIconClicked) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = "Search")
            }
        },
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
            titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
            actionIconContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
        ),
        modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp)
    )
}
```

Comment: This is still an experimental api, the modifier.height behavior is odd, the icon is not centerd as well, it just looks like it with 40 dp.
If you want a custom top bar I suggest to create one from scratch with a row.

Comment: Thanks Roman, suggestion much appreciated. I'll do that or maybe go back to M2 for the time being.